# Is there a way to conditionally copy the contents of a multidimensional NumPy array to another array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 2D array in numpy of arbitrary length, where each internal list (record) contains 10 elements. Is there a way to loop through the entire 2D array, and based upon conditions create a new array that contains only records that pass the tests?

Something akin to the below pseudocode:

```
array1 = np.array([1.142,2,3.10042,4,5,6,7.34141,8,9,10],[2.1535,3,4,5,6.000212,7,8,9,10,11],...)
array2 = np.empty(np.shape(array1)

for x in range(len(array1)):
    if array1[x][3] > 15:
        array2 = array1[x]
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: In your pseudocode, you create a NEW array each time the condition passes.  You aren't adding to or copyng to the array created with `empty`.

Comment: Yes you can loop through the rows of `array1`, and conditionally copy them to another array, or collect them in a list (generally better python that way).  That's basic python, for the most part.  The suggested answer is usually faster, because it makes use of compiled numpy methods, even if it does make temporary arrays.  That's a typical trade off.  Slow loops versus faster methods with more memory use.  Unless you take the extra step of coding it with a compiling tool like `numba`.

Comment: I realized this after I added an answer, but do you want to filter out the rows that do not satisfy your condition, or do you want to set them to zero? I.e. given a `(N, 10)` array, if only 5 out of `N` rows match your condition, do you expect an output of shape `(5, 10)`, or `(N, 10)` with only five non-zero rows?

Comment: Your question, specifically _"create a new array that contains only records that pass the tests"_ seem to indicate the former, but the creation of `array2 = np.empty(array1.shape)` seems to imply the latter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [boolean indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing):

```
array2 = np.zeros(np.shape(array1))

m = array1[:, 3]>15

array2[m] = array1[m]
```

Also note that you must initialize `array1` with [`numpy.zeros`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html), else all the non-assigned values will have arbitrary numbers.

Comment: Is there a recommended solution without creating a temporary array (`m`)?

Comment: @pts not really, you could use a walrus or duplicate the operation to have a one liner, but there is little interest. You can always delete `m` afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to select only those elements of `array1` where your condition is satisfied:

```
array2 = np.where(array1[:, 3, None] > 15, array1, 0)
```

This finds the rows where the third column of `array1` is greater than 15, and selects those rows from `array1` with zeros everywhere else.

Note that the `[:, 3, None]` indexing is used to prevent the automatic squeezing of the dimension so as to create a *column vector* which can be broadcast to the original array to select the entire row. Using `array1[:, 3] > 15` instead would result in

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (20,) (20,10) ()

---

Comparing the timing against [mozway's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77297489/843953), the `where` approach is ~2x faster on my computer:

```
import numpy as np
import timeit
def make_inputs(size):
    a = np.random.random((size, size))
    c = np.random.randint(size)
    v = np.random.random()
    return a, c, v

def f1(arr, col, val):
    array2 = np.zeros_like(arr)
    m = arr[:, col] > val
    array2[m] = arr[m]
    return array2

def f2(arr, col, val):
    return np.where(arr[:, col, None] > val, arr, 0)

sizes = [10, 100, 1000, 5000, 10_000, 50_000]
times = np.zeros((len(sizes), 2))

for i, s in enumerate(sizes):
    a, c, v = make_inputs(s)
    assert (f1(a, c, v) == f2(a, c, v)).all(), "Different outputs from both functions"
    times[i, 0] = timeit.timeit('f1(a, c, v)', globals=globals, number=10)
    times[i, 0] = timeit.timeit('f2(a, c, v)', globals=globals, number=10)
```

On my computer, this gives the following `times`, which shows a consistent ~2x speedup for `np.where` (labelled `f2` in the plot below) over the boolean indexing approach (labelled `f1`):

```
array([[9.20000020e-05, 4.53998800e-05],
       [1.47900078e-04, 9.87001695e-05],
       [4.83841999e-02, 1.88557999e-02],
       [1.02645030e+00, 5.64855800e-01],
       [4.05608600e+00, 2.33924000e+00],
       [8.85297001e+01, 5.98397732e+01]])
```

[image]